# ASTs: prefer inheritance or variants?

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, composite, boost-variant

In object oriented languages, it is fairly common to implement ASTs (Abstract Syntax Trees) using simple hierarchies (the Composite pattern), and to traverse them via visitors.

In functional programming languages, using variants/sum types, and then pattern matching, is the right approach.

C++ features both inheritance, and Boost.Variants.  I have written several AST hierarchies using inheritance, but I'd like to get some feedback from people who would have used the variant approach.  I'd like to know which one is the "best", in terms of performance (time and space), but also in terms of maintainability (easiness to create trees, and to traverse them).

I am especially interested in experience with implementation of hash-consing (keeping a single copy of each common subtree), possibly with Boost.Flyweight.

I am interested in battle field experience, not opinions.  This question was original closed as "opinion-based".  Which has never been the point...

Thanks!

Comment: Visitors (and variants thereof), please vote to reopen this question.

Comment: Simply stating "please reopen this question" without explaining why it should be reopened will accomplish nothing.

Comment: Because it was closed as "opinion-based" and never was.  I'm asking for facts.  I'm sorry if that was not clear. Cheers!